# flutter: extension class on abstract class

Tags: dart

I created an abstract class like this :

```
abstract class IRepository<T> {

}
```

After that I created an extension to this class :

```
extension Find<T> on IRepository<T>{

  T get find => .....;
}
```

Now in other class, I try to use this extension like this: `IRepository.find` but I got this error `The getter 'find' isn't defined for the type 'IRepository'.`?

I imported locally my extension class for sure but I still have this error ?

Comment: Extension methods works on objects. You don't seem to have created any object which implements IRepository

Comment: I have an abstract class and some classes implemented this abstract but I want to add extension to an abstract class because I want it usable for all concrete classes

Comment: That is also fine. But the error indicates you are trying to access the property directly (statically) on the class instead of on an object.

Comment: I am using Gex. I have an abstract class for repository and a concrete class on abstract class. Now I want to make an extension for find repository by getx `extension Find<T> on IRepository<T>{

  static T  find() => Get.find<T>();
}
`

Comment: Shouldn't `find` simply be a `static` method on `IRepository<T>`? No extension needed.

Comment: You can't. Extensions cannot be used to add static members to classes.

Comment: directly using static class in repository is not good best practise for solid to getting reference. so I am trying to find a better way, Other way is use other static class like center class

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate an object first and then try to use the find extensions. But abstract classes can't be instantiated. So you need to create some implementation first.

```
abstract class IRepository<T> {

}

class RepImpl extends IRepository<String>{

}


extension Find<T> on RepImpl{

  String get find => ...;
}
```

and Then Create an object from RepImpl and you can access find getter.

Answer (score 0):

Like HKN's answer, you need to create some implementation. You defined your `abstract` and `extension`, but there is no `implementation`. You need a class to implement the `IRepository` abstract class.

To do this add:

```
class IRepoImplementation implements IRepository {}
```

Now you should be able to call it like this:

```
Find(IRepoImplementation()).find;
```

If you want to call it this way instead: `IRepository.find` you have to use static. I can see in your comments that you prefer not to, but as far as i'm concerned Dart doesn't really support direct calling extensions on type without an instance. Extension methods are designed to be called on instances of the extended type, not on the type itself.

```
abstract class IRepository<T> {
  static Type find() {
    return Find<T>().find;
  }
}

extension Find<T> on IRepository<T> {
  Type get find => T;
}

void main() {
  Type result = IRepository.find();
  print(result);
}
```

Alternatively, instead of using abstract and extension you can also just implement a class to call it from.

```
class IRepository {
  static Find find = const Find();
}

class Find {
  const Find();
  T get find => ...;
}
```

You would then call it like this: `IRepository.Find.find`